# How about Create Desktop Application with C++, HTML5, CSS?

Tags: c++, html, user-interface, desktop-application

i need your suggestions about my idea with my team:
we want to create a platform or let me named it a framework the roll of this "framework" is:
make desktop application so easy and powrfull specially in styles cause it is based on HTML5, css, and the logic side base on c++, we want to create an intermediate tag-language (base on XML namespaces); to create the GUI and to bind the c++ code with, if we create this "framework", how about it's powerfull and usability, ....
we want to create this "framework" cause we are mastered c++, we hate the requirements of .net, java, ..., and we want to use the powerfull of html, css, javascript, c++, the main part in my idea is to make all the of the javascript, css and html under one tag-language 'gml' to make the UI creation and styling animating so easy for developers, ex: in HTML we should type:

```
<input id="gobutton" type="submit" value="Go!" />
```

and in css code:

```
input#gobutton{ 
cursor:pointer; /*forces the cursor to change to a hand when the button is hovered*/
padding:5px 25px; /*add some padding to the inside of the button*/
background:#35b128; /*the colour of the button*/
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0, .75); ... }
/***NOW STYLE THE BUTTON'S HOVER AND FOCUS STATES***/
input#gobutton:hover, input#gobutton:focus{
background-color :#399630; ....}
```

and in the framework that we aim to build: we create so easy ex "first view":

```
<button id="btn" content="Hello" margin="1,5.2,3,6" background="Red" Foreground="White"          ... > <Button.HoverStyle> 
// here we can make css code or 
<CssStyle> .... </CssStyle>
</Button.HoverStyle>
</Button>
```

this is the firt look on the idea, but we will make it with more care and study.

my question is: how about this idea? and it's usability. I do not have a great view on the web, i think whene i share this idea you will help me to decide. thanks
thanks before ...

Comment: TL;DR; **1st** format your code correctly here!

Comment: how about it now, sorry i am poor in english!

Comment: What is the question?!

Comment: @Biffen the question is: how about this idea? and it's usability. I do not have a great view on the web, i think whene i share this idea you will help me to decide. thanks

Comment: please guys read carefully the full question, just need your suggestions about this idea.

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer: give a look at Qt. You can easily create a window that has a webkit-based browser inside and where you can use custom urls to talk to C++ or inject C++ objects so they are directly accessible from Javascript. The code is portable on Linux, Windows and OsX. Note however they're pushing a declarative way alternative to html/css for defining the interface (qml).

Comment: @6502: yes i got a look, but the requirments to webkit and Qt and the installation steps very complex specially when you want to talk to c++ and get the callback, but my idea consists to make all of that inside one box like (wpf and C#). sure this idea will created to be cross-platform working.

Comment: You have made the question clearer but it's still both too broad and opinion based so I can't vote to open it sorry. You need a discussion forum, not a Q&A site.